# How to convert files from Cadence to Eagle CAD?

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, cadence, allegro

Is there any free software that can convert Cadence files (.dsn, .opj, .brd) into Eagle CAD files (.brd, .sch)?

Comment: A quick google search revealed these: [element14 forum thread](http://www.element14.com/community/thread/22898/l/orcad-sch-to-eagle-software) and [eaglecentral forum thread](http://www.eaglecentral.ca/forums/index.php/mv/msg/48028/149992/). You can also look at [cadsoftUSA ULP downloads](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/downloads/ulps?language=en).

Comment: If you ever get stuck doing translation by hand, importing gerbers onto a graphic layer and placing/routing over them can at least let you salvage the design thought which went into the original.

Answer (score 2):

Importing from different CAD packages often has issues.

There are three main parts: schematics, libraries (containing schematic symbols and PCB footprints) and PCB layout.

CAD packages can import them as individual's but do not necessarily import all three as a linked package.  This can cause issues for future maintenance of the boards and manufacturing issues due to footprint's not being verified and validated fully during the translation.

A safer and often shorter in the long term approach is to duplicate the library parts and verify all symbols and foot prints, followed be re-entering the schematics, (this will be trivial once all the parts are in the library) and re-laying out the PCB using the existing PCB files as a guide.

This is the only way you can be certain all parts used are correct, and you have not created or lost any artefacts during the PCB importation process.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool for the purpose , as of now. You have to rework.